# Rails5 - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "stocks" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, relational-database, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deploy my application to heroku and i face this Undefined table error.

Although i have tried a DB Drop, creation, this is still same.

I have seen a few similar questions over in here, but none resolved my issue.

```
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2018-01-15T15:25:53.695110 #398]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9b29a65ddf4e67b14324d55bddaef6bd/public/assets/jumbotron--032aba6cd1415006731040523573e7138c703aedc6d1f46b3622cbe4c9feec27.jpg
remote:        Stock Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "stocks" does not exist
remote:        LINE 1: SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
remote:        ^
remote:        : SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
remote:        /tmp/build_9b29a65ddf4e67b14324d55bddaef6bd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:614:in `async_exec'
```

Here is the schema i am using:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180112181551) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.string "phonenumber"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "address"
    t.text "gender"
    t.text "created_by"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "ordertype"
    t.jsonb "order_placed"
    t.float "totalprice"
    t.text "paymentmethod"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "customer_id"
  end

  create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "item_name"
    t.string "item_id"
    t.float "unit_price"
    t.float "tax"
    t.float "discount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**EDIT: Adding Migrations**

```
20171223044709_create_customers
20171223052206_customer_chnge_datatype_phonenu
20171224171909_create_orders
20171228162239_change_jsonb_field_name
20180101120347_adding_cust_id_to_orders
20180106214656_changing
20180112181551_create_stock
```

**Edit: Adding Models**

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
end
```

---

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :customer
 serialize(:order_placed, Array)
#accepts_nested_attributes_for :order
store_accessor :order_placed, :itemname, :quantity, :unitprice, :tax, :discount, :itemtotalprice

    ORDER_TYPE_LIST = ["Order","Take-Away","Home Delivery"]
    PAYMENT_METHOD_LIST = ["Cash","Card","Wallet"]

end
```

---

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord

has_many :orders

end
```

I have GUI calling in stocks table.
 Is this causing any issue ?

```
                    <select name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" id="order_place_id" class="form-control" style="width: 300px">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <% Stock.all.each do |stock| %>
                            <option value="<%= stock.item_name %>">
                                <%= stock.item_name %>
                            </option>
                        <% end %>
                    </select>

                </td>
```

Comment: did you run `rake db:migrate` to actually create tables ?

Comment: Following on @Sharj, you want to make sure to do `heroku run rake db:migrate -app YOUR_APP_NAME` (`rake db:migrate` only migrates on your local machine.)

Comment: Following command has been run already. Still the same issue.

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

`Running rake db:migrate on damp-beyond-28813... up, run.2763 (Free)
D, [2018-01-16T15:46:21.588921 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(5147461483620106980)
D, [2018-01-16T15:46:21.626582 #4] DEBUG -- :    (7.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
............. `

Comment: @Sharj Yes... I have run the command.

Comment: Can you add your models and migrations in here. It seems to me that when the migration is running, you may have a validation which triggers some SQL while your migrations are running

Comment: @uno_ordinary.... I have a Drop down which is supposed to load all its display values from the Data base table stocks.

Comment: Added Migratons and Models.... Thanks..!!!

Comment: The GUI should not be an issue, as the migration is run beforehand. Do you have any calls to `Stock` table before the actual `create_stock` migration ?

Comment: In the code i did not call Stock except for GUI. I deployed the application to heroku first thinking to run the migrations next. Then the Stock must have been called. Is my understanding correct? However, running migrations should have resolved the issue. But it is still on... sinking me down. :(

Comment: Any help is appreciated.... Advance thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved:
1. I commented all the Active record calls from GUI.
2. I tired inserting a record to table using rails seed then pushed the same to heroku.
3. Added GUI code and then check on local machine. Once working fine, deployed to Heroku.

During the time of deployment, Heroku found data as we already pushed some data via seed.

Hence no error thrown and issue resolved...

Cheers...!!!!